# How can i fetch the publication date of a Youtube Video using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, youtube

I have been developping a plugin on Firefox which fetches date from the html source code of Youtube Videos. I am trying to find a way to fetch the publication date of the video, however my function is not working. Can you help me find what's wrong, and help me come up with a fix ? Also, I cannot use the Youtube API or any exterior information source other thant the Youtube page itself.

My code works by looking through the html and then when it find "datePublished", it copies the content. here is the code

```
function getYouTubeVideoDate() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        browser.tabs.executeScript({ code: 'document.documentElement.outerHTML' })
            .then((result) => {
                const htmlContent = result[0];
                const regex = /"datePublished"\s*content="([^"]+)"/g;
                let match;
                while ((match = regex.exec(htmlContent)) !== null) {
                    const datePublished = match[1];
                    // Extract the date part (YYYY-MM-DD) from the full date-time string
                    const date = datePublished.split("T")[0];
                    resolve(date);
                    return;
                }
                reject("Publication date not found");
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                reject(error);
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: 1) If you have code that doesn't work, please add it to the question so we can help you to debug it. 2) Youtube has a comprehensive API. I would assume this would be a good place to start: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos